# Function won't print to canvas

Tags: javascript, function, canvas

I am working on a video game in javascript, but I cannot get my function to print to the canvas. I'm not getting any errors, so I can't pinpoint why this is happening. This function is supposed to take in the name of the image to concat onto a .png stored in a separate Images file, an x and y location, the height and width of the image, and the canvas and context for it to print on. Below is my code.

```
function loadCanvas(){

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

//Sprite function
var sprite = function(imageName, imageX, imageY, imageHeight, imageWidth, context, canvas){
    this.imageName = imageName;
    this.imageX = imageX;
    this.imageY = imageY;
    this.imageHeight = imageHeight;
    this.imageWidth = imageWidth;
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.context = context;
}

//Sprite draw function
sprite.prototype.draw = function(){
        var character = new Image();
        character.src = "../Images/" + this.imageName + ".png";
        var cont = this.context;
        character.onload = function(){
            cont.drawImage(character, this.imageX, this.imageY, this.imageWidth, this.imageHeight);
        }
}

sprite.prototype.getHeight = function(){
        return this.imageHeight;
    }

    sprite.prototype.getWidth = function(){
        return this.imageWidth;
    }

    sprite.prototype.getX = function(){
        return this.imageX;
    }

    sprite.prototype.getY = function(){
        return this.imageY;
    }

    sprite.prototype.moveUpX = function(e){
        this.imageX = (this.imageX + e);
    }

    sprite.prototype.moveUpY = function(e){
        this.imageY = (this.imageY + e);
    }

    sprite.prototype.moveBackX = function(e){
        this.imageX = (this.imageX - e);
    }

    sprite.prototype.moveBackY = function(e){
        this.imageY = (this.imageY - e);
    }

    sprite.prototype.changeImage = function(e){
        this.imageName = e;
    }

    sprite.prototype.getImage = function(){
        return this.imageName;
    }

    sprite.prototype.changeX = function(e){
        this.imageX = e;
    }

    sprite.prototype.changeY = function(e){
        this.imageY = e;
    }

    sprite.prototype.getContext = function(){
        return this.context;
    }

var sprites = [];
sprites[1]= new sprite("RoomOne", 0, 0, 800, 400, context, canvas);
sprites[1].draw();

}
```

Here is my HTML, all of the above code is wrapped in the "loadCanvas" function:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<script src = 'game.js'></script>


</head>

<body onload = "loadCanvas()">

<canvas id='canvas' width="800" height="400" style="border:0px solid  #c3c3c3;">
This is not supported in your browser.
</canvas>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your **html** as well ?

Comment: I just updated it, hopefully this helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this lines:

```
character.onload = function(){
    // "this" variable is not that you expect,
    // "this" refers to "window" object.
    // yon can try to console.log(this);
    cont.drawImage(character, this.imageX, this.imageY, this.imageWidth, this.imageHeight);
}
```

You need to pass expected `this` to function, using [.bind(this)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) or save `this` in variable outside from function.

So, solution using .bind:

```
//Sprite draw function
sprite.prototype.draw = function(){
        var character = new Image();
        character.src = "../Images/" + this.imageName + ".png";
        var cont = this.context;
        character.onload = function(){
            cont.drawImage(character, this.imageX, this.imageY, this.imageWidth, this.imageHeight);
        }.bind(this);
}
```

and solution using variable:

```
//Sprite draw function
sprite.prototype.draw = function(){
        var character = new Image();
        character.src = "../Images/" + this.imageName + ".png";
        var cont = this.context;
        var self = this;

        character.onload = function(){
            cont.drawImage(character, self.imageX, self.imageY, self.imageWidth, self.imageHeight);
        };
}
```

Comment: It would be useful for you to read a little bit about `this` in JavaScript, because it is very different from `this` in other languages. [This](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) link would help, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Found this code snippet:

```
   window.onload = function() {
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
var img=document.getElementById("scream");
ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
```

};

Not sure why you are using **this.**  .